# Swift concatenate two Ranges

Tags: ios, swift

I have two Ranges:

```
let r1: Range<Int> = 1...3
let r2: Range<Int> = 10...12
```

Is there a Swift way to concat/join the two ranges such that I can iterate over both of them in one `for` loop?

```
for i in joined_r1_and_r2 {
    print(i)
}
```

Where the results would be:

```
1
2
3
10
11
12
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a nested array and then join them.

```
// swift 3:
for i in [r1, r2].joined() {
    print(i)
}
```

The result of `joined()` here is a `FlattenBidirectionalCollection` which means it won't allocate another array.

(If you are stuck with Swift 2, use `.flatten()` instead of `.joined()`.)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because it has teached be more about the internal collection types. I still have to admire the designers of Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
let r1 = 1...3
let r2 = 10...12

for i in Array(r1) + Array(r2) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: This creates intermediate arrays which I'd like to avoid

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative would be:

```
var combined = [Int]
combined.append(contentsOf: 1...3)
combined.append(contentsOf: 10...12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert them to another structure because ranges have to be continuous.

One possible way:

```
let r1: Range<Int> = 1...3
let r2: Range<Int> = 10...12

for i in ([r1, r2].joinWithSeparator([])) {
    print(i)
}
```

There are multiple ways to achieve the same, I have used the one that is easily scalable to more ranges. `flatten` in [kennytm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543790/669586) is a better choice.

Of course, you can also simply iterate in a nested `for`:

```
for r in [r1, r2] {
    for i in r {
        print(i)
    }
}
```